# Implementing a Google Pay with Stripe Gateway in web

Tags: stripe-payments, google-pay

I have a problem when implementing the Google Pay api, i cant perform a payment. I implemented the the Google Pay api the same as the documentation say, and i saw i need to provide a gateway provider. I provided the following object:

```
  "gateway": "stripe"
  "stripe:version": "2018-10-31"
  "stripe:publishableKey": "YOUR_PUBLIC_STRIPE_KEY"
```

Everything work as expected, i can see the GPay button i can open it and choose my card, but when i click pay, i can see in the console a json token object  returned from Google Pay api, i dont know what are the next steps, if somebody have experience with that please help.

I tried with examples from the Google Pay api, also look the Stripe documentation but i didnt find where i need to pass this token object from Google Pay api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next step once you received the token from Google Pay is to perform the actual authorization by calling the respective Stripe APIs.

1. Call the [`/v1/payment_methods`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create?lang=curl#create_payment_method-card) API with the token you received in the response from Google Pay: `paymentData.paymentMethodData.tokenizationData.token.id`

   ```
   curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_methods \
   -u sk_test_your_secret: \
   -d type=card \
   -d "card[token]"=tok_abc1234
   ```
2. In the response you will receive an `id`. Use it to finally call the [`/v1/payment_intents`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents?lang=curl) API:

   ```
   curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents \
     -u sk_test_your_secret: \
     -X "POST" \
     -d amount=100 \
     -d payment_method=pm_your_pm \
     -d currency=usd
   ```

Additional API calls may be needed depending on the status of the Payment Intent. For more information on how Payment Intents work please see: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/intents

**Update:**

There is an even simpler way to charge a user by passing the `paymentData.paymentMethodData.tokenizationData.token.id` to the [`/v1/charges`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object) API directly:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges \
  -u sk_test_your_secret: \
  -d amount=100 \
  -d currency=usd \
  -d source=tok_abc1234
```