# Connecting Stripe to Google Pay: Error "IntegrationError: confirmCardPayment: Expected payment_method, or source, not payment_method_data."

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, google-pay

I am trying to integrate Stripe with Google Pay using the following code:

```
async function processPayment(paymentData) {
    const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
    const paymentIntent = {
        type: 'card',
        card: {
            token: paymentData.paymentMethodData.tokenizationData.token
        }
    };
    try{
        var result = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
            'CLIENT_SECRET',
            {
                payment_method_data: paymentIntent
            });
        console.log('processPayment result' + result);
    }
    catch(err){
        console.error('processPayment error' + err);
    }
```

However, when I try to execute the code, I encounter the following error: "IntegrationError: confirmCardPayment: Expected payment_method, or source, not payment_method_data." Although in the Stripe account console logs, I receive a 200 Status Code.

Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu6cR.png)

I have tried to use payment_method instead payment_method_data but faced to following error “A token may not be passed in as a PaymentMethod. Instead, use payment_method_data with type=card and card[token]=TOKEN.“

Comment: What docs are you following to integrate Stripe with Google Pay?  Have you tried following the Payment Request Button integration guide? https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button

Comment: I can not use the Payment Request Button because I am running google pay from my WebGL game

Comment: It's not clear here what the `paymentData` is here.  Following this doc (https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment#stripe_confirm_card_payment-token) you need to pass a Stripe Token (https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens).  Is that what is in the data?

Comment: @GevorgChobanyan you first have to create a payment method before creating an intent. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75804915/implementing-a-google-pay-with-stripe-gateway-in-web/75827720#75827720